# User inputs exact number of elements into an array

Tags: javascript, arrays

I need to limit the number of elements within the array using separate function with arguments *N* and *x* where *N* is the number of elements within the array *x*.

First, user enters *N*; second, **exactly** *N* elements into an array *x*

Comment: what do you mean by *relate*? please add an example of input and wanted output.

Comment: do you want to limit N number of elements to "array"?

Comment: It sounds like you're saying you want to get the first `n` number of elements from array `x`, but it's not clear.  Speak plainly and it will be easier to understand.  Also, look here... https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice

Comment: where does the input takes place?

Comment: @thaveethugce it doesn't limit but defines the EXACT number of elements in array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could take the length for a new array and map all inputs.

```js
function execute(length) {
    return Array.from({ length }, (_, i) => prompt('Enter value at index ' + i + ':'));
}

console.log(execute(3));
```

Comment: Can you write this code without using "prompt" but through inputting the same info in console?

Comment: you could replace `prompt` with a different input, which i do not know.

Answer (score 0):

below will give you the part you need, if the array is not long enough, it will be populated with undefined:

```
function giveMeNofX(N,x) {
    return (x instanceof Array ? x : []).slice(0,N).concat(Array.apply(null,Array(N))).slice(0,N)
}

giveMeNofX(2,[1,2,3]) //1,2
giveMeNofX(100,[1,2,3]) //1,2,3,undefined.....
```

Based on what you want, `freeze` or `seal` the returned array.